# BST traversal recursion faster than yield from

Tags: python, python-3.x

Working with a KD-Tree that is searched using HyperRectangles, the specifics of this can be easily Googled so I leave that up to your interests. I was searching something related to optimizing a portion of a regional query, when I came across the `yield from` syntax; thus highlighting its use over tail recursive functions since Python does not have those optimized.

I implemented my two traversal functions (one of which is nested) using this syntax to do some testing, and it turns out that it is actually slower than the recursive methods, though I am not sure why (but I believe it to be something with the nested function after doing some quick testing).

Caller:

```
def search(node, point, eps):
    region = make_region(point, eps)
    return [found 
            for found 
            in range_search(node, region) 
            if sqdist(found, point) <= (eps ** 2)
            ]
```

Outer (recursive):

```
def range_search(node, region, found=None):
    if found is None:
        found = []
    if node.is_leaf():
        found.append(node.value)
    else:
        if region.contains(node.bounds):
            dissolve(node, found)
        elif region.intersects(node.bounds):
            if node.left:
                range_search(node.left, region, found)
            if node.right:
                range_search(node.right, region, found)
    return found
```

Inner (recursive):

```
def dissolve(node, found):
    if not node.is_leaf():
        if node.left:
            dissolve(node.left, found)
        if node.right:
            dissolve(node.right, found)
    else:
        found.append(node.value)
```

Outer (generator):

```
def range_search(node, region):
    if node.is_leaf():
        yield node.value
    else:
        if region.contains(node.bounds):
            yield from dissolve(node)
        elif region.intersects(node.bounds):
            yield from range_search(node.left, region) if node.left else ()
            yield from range_search(node.right, region) if node.right else ()
```

Inner (generator):

```
def dissolve(node):
    if node:
        yield from dissolve(node.left) if node.left else ()
        if node.is_leaf():
            yield node.value
        yield from dissolve(node.right) if node.right else ()
```

Times are super far apart, but never-the-less I would've thought that the recursion would've been slower if Python is not optimized for it but it is for iteration with things like generators.

For example, running 20K points through the `search()` method with recursion the program finishes in 2.18s, while generators finish in 2.5s; again, nothing drastic just unexpected. Did I incorrectly convert the functions from recursive to generation?

Comment: the presented variants return different things: some return a `list` and some are generators.

Comment: @RonKlein And why does that matter to performance? If anything that impacts storage, where returning the list `found` is then stored in main memory and iterated over in the caller's list comprehension; by using the `yield` and `yield from` syntax I am simply not storing the interim list but only the final list in caller.

Comment: depends on the actual implementation. Maybe filling the list has more system level optimizations, such as branch prediction, while `yield`ing through a generator costs with an implicit state management.